# QVector: no match for 'operator+'

Tags: qt, qstring

I am passing a QVector from one window to another, I want to append the value present in QVector from previous window to a QString in present window. I get the error when I perform the addition `no match for 'operator+'`.

Here is my code:

Window1.cpp

```
void SelectOS::processNextButton()
{
    if(ui->win32->isChecked()){
        QString path;
        path = qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/WIN/32Bit";
        so->osName.push_back(path);
        SelectSoftware *ss = new SelectSoftware();
        this->hide();
        ss->show();
    }
}

QVector<QString> SelectOS::getosName(){
    so = new SelectOS();
    return so->osName;
}
```

Window2.cpp

```
void SelectSoftware::getSoftwareDetails()
{

    SelectOS *so = new SelectOS();
    SelectSoftware *ss = new SelectSoftware();
    ss->os = so->getosName();

    QString fileName = ss->os + "/" +SOFTWARELIST; // Here I get the error...

    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        QString msg = "Could not find the file " + fileName;
        errorExit(msg);
    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        processLine(line.toLower());
    }
}
```

Help me, thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SOFTWARELIST` is a simple QString:

```
QString fileName = QString( "%1/%2" )
                  .arg( ss->os.last() )
                  .arg( SOFTWARELIST );
```

This means you are creating a QString with placeholders `%1` and `%2` where `%1` will be replaced by the result of `ss->os.last()` which returns the last item in the vector and `%2` will be replaced by whatever `SOFTWARELIST` is.

If `SOFTWARELIST` is a vector as well, you will need to call e.g. `.last()` on it as well.

Comment: I want to pass list of String variables from one Window to another, which one i need to use? QList type or QString or QVector? >> And the above one is crashing the application :(

Comment: `QVector` is perfectly fine for doing that, just like `QList`. But are you trying to create a file name from all the entries in the list? Edit your question to contain an example file name, please, and show the definition of `SOFTWARELIST`.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: Passing the variables from one Window to another is not the problem. Your problem is the part where you build the file name.

Comment: No no, `SOFTWARELIST` is a name of the texfile which is defined already `#define SOFTWARELIST softwarelist.txt`. I will tell me problem now: I've 8 windows in my application, first is the login window, from 3rd window, i need to pass the arguments to and forth.. From one window, I passed QVector to second window its like `Next` but again if I want to access the 1st Window's values, I cannot define in 2nd Window, it shows empty and application is crashing too

Answer (score 0):

QVector is a container class, which holds *set* of something. In your example set of QString's. So then you try to form a fileName which is a QString you obviously cannot add to a fileName QString list of other Qstring's. (truly saying you can, but not with '+' operator and slightly different code). 
Honestly I didn't got straight away why you actually passing QVector if you only need an application path I would suggest to use just QString.